# Panopoly, custom module and javascript rendering error

Tags: 7, javascript, distributions

I have created a custom module that creates a jquery dynamic menu displayed as a slider in the left part of the screen. When clicking 'customize this page' the menu is activated and shows an image over which user can open the layer when moving his mouse. After saving the content, when clicking on 'customize this page' for the second time, the settings of the left hidden slider is lost and the menu is displayed in bulk on the top of the content region.

I can't see any difference between the source codes of those two different situations and I suspect Panopoly cache or save settings interfering with the rendering of the customized javascript.

Actually, the javascript is located in the theme/js folder.

Thank you for any idea about this.